# PHP cURL Content-Type is not set

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I have a simple web service that I would like to connect with. In order to post some `XML`, which will be properly proceeded on the web service side, I need to prepare a proper request. I am using `cURL` for this like that:

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();

    if (FALSE === $ch)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"192.168.1.37");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/xml',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:  "));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml);

    $request=  curl_getinfo($ch);
    var_dump($request);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if (false === $content) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Everything should be ok. First I am displaying the request body from `curl_getinfo($ch);` and then i am showing the response from `$content` variable.

Only restriction for request to be sent to the server is `Content-Type` header - it MUST be `application/xml` otherwise server will respond with an error ( It is not my idea and I can't do anything about it)

Here is output request:

`array(21) { ["url"]=> string(68) "192.168.1.37" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(0) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } }`

and response is `HTTP 400 Bad Request`

What I can see from that is `["content_type"]=> NULL` but I set this variable in my PHP code...

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Try to see this Post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823810/set-http-request-content-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823810/set-http-request-content-type)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You are setting HTTP_HEADER twice:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/xml',
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                            ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:  "));
```

I guess that is the problem. The second time you set it, you delete the first setting.

Comment: Of course it was It! Can't believe it that was so stupid mistake. Thank You Legionar!

Comment: Ugh an issue with copy paste code. I had the exact same line causing the exact same problem. Upvoted