# Curl Post Http Headers Issue

Tags: php, http, post, curl, http-headers

Content type always null when passing on production server

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xxxxx/oauth2/token");
$params = http_build_query(array(
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://xxxx',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => '3423424234'
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',$encodeID)); //setting custom header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}

curl_close($curl);
```

and this is my output from the following curl response

```
["url"]=> string(41) "https://xxxx/oauth2/token" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(0) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(0) ["local_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["local_port"]=> int(0)
```

Please help thanxs :-)

Comment: try rewriting the http header array as the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823810/set-http-request-content-type)

Comment: Tried already but same result

Comment: What's in the `$encodeID` ?

Comment: `Authorization: Basic base64encode(client_id:client_secret)`

Comment: Any possibility to add the content-length to the headers and test it? because the links that I have visited have content-length accompanying the content-type.

Comment: You don't even need to set that content-type yourself as that's what curl defaults to with a "normal" post...

Comment: Worked on localhost but not in production enivornment or this because something disable in production? @DanielStenberg

Comment: cURL isn't actually making the request.  Does your production server have the CA certificate installed that is used by that site?  If you add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` in production does it then work?  This means its a certificate problem.

Comment: Download CA certificate on folder but still something missing or http post request have security protocols in server? @drew010